# If I resubmit an approved Open Graph action will its current permissions be removed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I want to resubmit an existing action so that it gets the new News Feed previews (larger, more prominent object links, which more recently submitted actions are generating). If I resubmit the action, will it be publicly unavailable until re-approved?

UPDATE:

For everyone's reference (and reassurance), this is what a resubmitted live action looks like within the Developer dashboard:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you resubmit the action, it will not affect the status of your already live submission. :)

You can have a look here: [Resubmitting Actions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/submission-process/opengraph/overview/#resubmit)